# A proverb about it's a sin not to take what's you catch

Tags: proverbs

I may have dreamed this but I remember my Japanese teacher telling our class (23yr ago) about a Japanese proverb that went something like:

> It's sin not to take the fish you catch

The teacher explained this to mean, men use this proverb to justify cheating. That it means, if a woman offers herself it's a sin not to accept.

What is this proverb?

Comment: 「据え膳食わぬは男の恥」ってやつですかね？？違うかも

Comment: 話の具合的に、「据え膳食わぬは男の恥」と「釣った魚にエサはやらぬ」がごっちゃになってるんですかね…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest phrase in Japanese would be [据え膳食わぬは男の恥](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8D%AE%E3%81%88%E8%86%B3%E9%A3%9F%E3%82%8F%E3%81%AC%E3%81%AF%E7%94%B7%E3%81%AE%E6%81%A5), but it says nothing about fish. The literal meaning of this phrase is "Not eating the meal set before him is a man's shame".

Comment: That's probably it. Thanks